# Python Pandas: Cumulative Sum based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I am calculating the value for the *Total ‘1st’ Position* column (table below) and would like to do this using multiple conditions.

I want *Total ‘1st’ Position* to reflect the number of times a given athlete has won a race (as of a given day).

For example... see below that Steve's *Total 1st Position* increments by 1 when: Athlete = Steve and Position = 1. I want to do this for all athletes.

[image]

I have tried the following...

```
df['Total 1st Position'] = ((df['Position'] == '1') & (df['Athlete'] == df['Athlete'])).cumsum()
```

...but this only returns a running sum of the number of times df['Position'] == '1'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you post your dataframe in text format please?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it this way:

```
df = your_file

df.loc[(df['Position'] == 1), 'firsts'] = 1
df=df.fillna(0)

df['Total 1st Position'] = (df['firsts']*df['Position']).groupby(df['Athlete']).cumsum()
```

If we run your data frame through this we get the following:

```
   Race Day Athlete  Position  firsts  Total 1st Position
0     Day 1   Steve         1     1.0                 1.0
1     Day 1    Jane         2     0.0                 0.0
2     Day 1    Bill         3     0.0                 0.0
3     Day 2    Bill         1     1.0                 1.0
4     Day 2   Steve         2     0.0                 1.0
5     Day 2    Jane         3     0.0                 0.0
6     Day 3    Jane         1     1.0                 1.0
7     Day 3    Bill         2     0.0                 1.0
8     Day 3   Steve         3     0.0                 1.0
9     Day 4   Steve         1     1.0                 2.0
10    Day 4    Jane         2     0.0                 1.0
11    Day 4    Bill         3     0.0                 1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a temporary column to indicate wins, then use `.groupby` with `.cumsum` on that:

```
df['won'] = (df['Position'] == '1') * 1
df['Total 1st Position'] = df.groupby('Athlete').won.cumsum()
```

Comment: Thanks for this :-) How as a next step could I count the respective number of times each runner raced, on a cumulative basis?

Comment: Use `.cumcount()` instead: `df.groupby('Athlete').cumcount()`